# android SharedPreferences or SQLite

Tags: android

if I want to save large data such as rss feeds or Topics in my app

do I have to use SQLite or SharedPreferences

dose SharedPreferences save information as shared information ? like any other app can use them ?

Comment: Please accept an answer to mark your question as answered. Why and how? See: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

In this case you are better with the `SQLite` option, that's design to store a large amounts of data while shared preferences were designed to store a relatively small amounts in a shape of key, value pairs.

and not the name is a bit confusing but it means that those preferences are shared to all your application activities and not to other applications.

Answer (score 1):

No, you probably want some type of database or stored file. [Shared Prefs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) are for saving persistent data in a `("key", value)` pair like maybe a login id or some sort of status. You won't store a "lot" of data in it. It is to persist data in your app even when it closes. You can read more about [Storage Options here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

If you are wanting to share data with other applications then you may want to look into [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html)

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Shared Prefs is for fewer key-value items, simpler to use. It can be private or public. You decide.

SQLite is for a lot of data, more complex to use. It is private.

Answer (score 1):

`SharedPreferences` should be only used for storing primitive and limited data, while `SQL` is designed for structured and large amounts of data. As you want to store large amounts of data, you also might want to search or do other useful transformations with it, so `SQL` is what you want to use as it provides these features. `SharedPreferences` are dumb `key-value` or `key-values` holders without real processing features.

`SharedPreferences` are not shared with other application, but it could be possible (while it was never intended) to allow other applications to access them with some additional work.

It is possible to configure your application as service provider for other applications. This allows foreign applications to work with your private `SQL`-DB (or more abstract API). It is also possible (and recommended) to limit the access to your DB, that no third party app is able to mess with your valuable data.